# Encontrar path a archivo en un WAR

Tags: java, maven, jasper, war

Buen día comunidad.

Tengo el siguiente problema necesito tomar el path de un archivo .jasper el cual va empaquetado en un **WAR**. El archivo se encuantra en la siguiente ruta dentro del tomcat: **appName/WEB-INF/classes/ReporteIva.jasper**

[image: error tomcat]

Llevo ya varios días intentando con varias formas sin embargo no sé como puedo tomar ese **PATH**.

Estos son algunos ejemplos:

```java
String reporteIva = "src/main/resources/ReporteIva.jasper";

String test = getClass().getResource(reporteIva).toString();
String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath() + reporteIva;
```

**Nota:** Tal cual está funciona en mi ambiente de desarollo sin embargo al exportar el **WAR** la ruta cambia pero no sé a cual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas la URL al archivo:

String reporteIva = "ReporteIva.jasper";

```
// la url como String
String test = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(reporteIva).toString();
```

Si necesitas leer el contenido del archivo:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reporteIva);
```

Cuando usas `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` va el path relativo desde la raiz del classpath (sin la / inicial).

Cuando usas `this.getClass().getResource()` va el path absoluto (desde la raíz del classpath), o el path relativo desde el package donde está la clase de `this`.

Si el archivo estuviera en `src/main/resources/jasper/ReporteIva.jasper`, para este ejemplo, `String reporteIva` sería `"jasper/ReporteIva.jasper";`.

Comment: muchas gracias sin embargo solo tuve que hacer una modificacion y fue borrar la parte del string la cadena **file:**